# php submit with PDO SQL issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wanted to change from normal mysql query to PDO but since that time I can't even track the fault back.

Is there anyone out there to help me? Any hint would be appreciated!

Q1: what is wrong? Q2: how can the fault be tracked generally?

```
<?php
// Check if add button active, start this
if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
 $new=htmlspecialchars($_POST['newgroup']);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO contactgroups (status, gr_name) VALUES(1, : new )";
 $sql->bindvalue( ': new', $new);
 $sql->execute();
 $arr = $sql->errorInfo();
 echo $arr;
 echo  "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=groups.php\">";
}
?>

<form id="group-in" method="post" action="groups.php">
Add new Distribution group: <input type="text" name="newgroup" placeholder="name..."> <input type="submit" name="create" value="Create new">
Rename groupname: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $result['gr_name']; ?>"> <input type="submit" name="rename" value="Rename">
</form>
```

the $_POST is coming, the SQL is running but after the bindPARAM/bindVALUE nothing comes...

Comment: +1 @ Jürgen Thelen: that was the other fault!!!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never prepare your sql statement above.

In order to run, you would first need to initialize the DB and create a new PDO instance. Assuming you have this done before:

```
<?php
// Check if add button active, start this
if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
 $new=htmlspecialchars($_POST['newgroup']);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO contactgroups (status, gr_name) VALUES(1, : new )";
 $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindvalue( ': new', $new);
 $stmt->execute();
 $arr = $stmt->errorInfo();
 echo $arr;
 echo  "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=groups.php\">";
}
?>
```

You can wrap a function/code bit with a try/catch statement and enable exception handling with PDO to get better insight into errors going forward.

Comment: thanks the prepare was definitely one of the error. Now I've got 42000 errorcode??? no google result?